# Read file in pom.xml from a dependency - Maven

Tags: maven

has any way to read a file inside on dependency?

For example, I have my pom.xml and I using the maven-antrun-plugin to copy the .war generated to my remote server, but i need to pass two attributes: keyfile and knowhosts, today, I have these files inside my project, in java/resources path, but i would like to know if has any way to wrapper these files in a .jar, and use this as dependency in my project, and read theses files from this dependency.

Thank very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correct so let's summarize your question how I understand it:

1. You have a project based on Maven and build a WAR file for deployment on an application server.
2. In your current situation you have two files in your projects resource folder that you read from/with your project code.
3. You want a situation that the two files are packed in a custom jar file and put that file as dependency on the classpath/in the pom file. The question is if you can still read them from your project code.

Yes, that's possible. If you add the dependency to the dependency list in the pom file the file will be also included in the war file and then available on the classpath of your application. 
Only if your project jar is marked as sealed it won't work (Sealed jar files only can read classed from it's jar file and I think that is also not possible for resource files).

If this is also a good solution is more complex to answer and I can't answer that with the current limited info I have about your project.

Comment: Hi Jasper, thank you very much! you undertood correctly my question. I found the solutuion using the maven-dependency-plugin